# C# - How to keep an executable running in memory

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is it possible to keep an executable in memory in the below circumstance, baring in mind it is reading different lines of a text file:

```
 Process.Start("cmd.exe", 
               "/c test.exe \"" + exename + "\" > output.txt").WaitForExit();
```

To clarify, test.exe would not have to create a separate instance for every line that is read and then run.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Not with this line, but overall.

Comment: Can you please share that why do you want to do so?

Comment: I want to be able to scan a group of files (listed in a text file), but to be able to scan all of these files with only a instance of the program running

Comment: Rewrite your program to accept the text file with files to scan as input instead of calling it with one file at a time.

Comment: Just curious, why the downvotes? The question is pretty clear and concise. Strange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to develop your application as a windows service instead.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=VS.100).aspx

You will then have more control over application lifetime among other things.

If you already have the application written then it should be trivial to convert to a windows service.

Comment: It'll be interesting to see Michael try to do this, if he doesn't already know how to read multiple files with a single execution of the program.

Comment: True. There'll be more questions to come I'm sure.